# textarea not filling div in css

Tags: css

I'm trying to fit the textarea "todo" in the div "box_3" but unfortunately it's looking like in the picture and I'm not able to find the error. I assume it has to do with the size of box_3 and the display: grid but I can't solve it.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container_index {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 41vh 41vh;
}

.box_1 {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;


}

.box_2 {
    background-color: green;
    grid-column: 1 / 3 ;
    grid-row: 2 / -2;


}

.box_3 {
    display: grid;
    grid-row: 3 / -3;
    grid-column: auto;
    background-color: white;
    place-content: start center;
    background-color: red;

}

.todo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    resize: none;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="container_index">
        <div class="box_1"><h2>Test</h2></div>
        <div class="box_2"><h2>Test</h2></div>
        <div class="box_3">
            <textarea class="todo"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVn7V.png)

I tried to change the css multiple times without results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to remove `display: grid;` from the parent (`.box_3`)

Or just remove `place-content: start center;`

More info about [place-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-content)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container_index {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 41vh 41vh;
}

.box_1 {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;


}

.box_2 {
    background-color: green;
    grid-column: 1 / 3 ;
    grid-row: 2 / -2;


}

.box_3 {
    grid-row: 3 / -3;
    grid-column: auto;
    background-color: white;
    place-content: start center;
    background-color: red;

}

.todo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    resize: none;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="container_index">
        <div class="box_1"><h2>Test</h2></div>
        <div class="box_2"><h2>Test</h2></div>
        <div class="box_3">
            <textarea class="todo"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! But why? :D Why don't I need to add a display: grid here?

Comment: display : grid make *place-content: start center;* effectif so better solution is to remove the place-content

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `place-contnet: start center;` property from `.box_3` so that the textarea will cover while 3rd box div

```
 .container_index {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 50vh 50vh;
}

.box_3 {
    display: grid;
    grid-row: 3 / -3;
    grid-column: auto;
    /* background-color: white; */
    /* place-content: start center; */
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Removing the place-content property makes the textarea take the whole space in the container for me. As stated in a previous reply, unless you want to align other elements in box_3, you can remove the display: grid as well.

```
.box_3 {
    display: grid;
    grid-row: 3 / -3;
    grid-column: auto;
    background-color: white;
    /* place-content: start center; */
    background-color: red;
}
```